# Allocation of a ByteBuffer on the same thread as the selection process

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

Say the `Selector` just told me there was a read event ready. First thing I do is allocate a `ByteBuffer`... on the same thread as my selected keys `Iterator`.

if this `ByteBuffer` was big enough (i would be using up to 4096 bytes in this case) would this significantly slow down my selection process?

Please discuss both direct and heap based `ByteBuffer`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should have allocated a ByteBuffer for the channel when you accepted or connected it. Maybe two, one for reading and one for writing. You would store these as session variables via the key attachments. Allocating a new BB per selection event doesn't make sense. What for example if you only read a partial message last time?